# Sessions and session variables are not working

Tags: php

I have a login script in Php. If the credentials are correct then the session is started, session variables are set and then redirected to the profile page. In the profile page, I have a script that redirects the user back to login page if they have not logged in.

Now, whenever I enter the correct credentials of the user and click on login, it redirects me back to the login page. To solve it, I commented out the code which was responsible for the redirection back to the login page. As a result, I got access to the profile page but I could not access the session variables.
And sometimes this code runs perfectly while sometimes it shows the above-stated problem.

The login code is as shown in the picture :

```
session_start();
require_once 'includes/config.php'; 
   if(isset($_POST['login'])){ 
    $user = trim($_POST['username']); 
    $pass = trim($_POST['password']);
    $ch = $_POST['position'];
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT C_Name, PAN_id, Password FROM master_registration WHERE PAN_id = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$user);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
           $username = $row["PAN_id"];
           $Name = $row["C_Name"];
           $hash = $row["Password"];
           if(password_verify($pass, $hash)) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                $_SESSION["Name"] = $Name;
                header("Location: main_folder/master/profile.php");
```

[Login page code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM5Wq.png)

The profile page code is as shown in the picture:

```
 session_start();
 require_once '../../includes/config.php';
 if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] !== true){
     header("location:../../index.php");
     exit;
 }
 $user = $_SESSION['username'];
```

[profile page code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NMTY.png)

The seems fine, but there is a problem in sessions, plus it works in localhost but when I hosted in CPanel the problem starts.

Please help anyone...

Comment: Please put your code here, not a picture of it.

Comment: Please add all relevant code to your question - otherwise it is likely that the question will be closed.

Comment: `$username_err` and `$password_err` - if these are not defined before `if( empty( $username_err ).....` you'll get an error. Have you got `error_reporting` enabled? Have you checked your PHP error log?

Comment: I have inserted my code in the question. Please, any suggestions? please.

Comment: Why is there a second `session_start` inside the if block that verifies the password? The session _is_ already started, calling the function again now will cause a Notice. (If you didn't see one yet, you probably don't have proper PHP error reporting enabled, so go do that first now!)

Comment: what would happen if we log in continuously without proper logout i.e. what if the sessions remained undestroyed due to improper logout?.

Comment: @sudarshan For debugging purposes, add a `var_dump(session_id(), $_SESSION);` call to your code to see if you get a new session or load an existing session and to check the content of your session.

Comment: Your boolean logic is incorrect; `!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] !== true` should be `!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] !== true`, or  use `!(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true))`. See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws); `A && B` inverted is `!A || !B`, or simply `!(A && B)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Cpanel need config on the PHP SESSION, php.ini
First yo can check  the CPanel **session.save_path** and enabel  **output_buffering**   . 
to used **phpinfo()** 
Your code its correct. but if try session_start(); to inculed the config.php file

Answer (score -1):

Change your profile pic code with this code...
Your logic is incorrect thatswhy you are redirected everytime

```
if(!$_SESSION['loggedin']) {
header("location: ../../index.php");
exit() ;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. Even if I removed this particular snippet, I could access the profile page but couldn't access the value of the session variables that were set in the login page.

Comment: Then check if session variable is enabled or not on your cpanel